# Call to glDeleteBuffersARB results in segfault

Tags: c++, opengl, vbo

I am attempting to dynamically delete VBOs in my application in order to create new VBOs that are of different sizes. However, when my program attempts to delete them it crashes with a segmentation fault.

Below is my code that allocates the VBO:

```
glGenBuffersARB(1, &_vertexBufferID);
glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBufferID);
glBufferDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                _pMetadata->vertexBufferSize(),
                NULL,
                GL_STATIC_DRAW)
```

Data is periodically added to the VBO in the following code:

```
glBindBufferARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBufferID);
glBufferSubDataARB(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
                   _pMetadata->vertexSubBufferOffset(),
                   _pMetadata->vertexSubBufferSize(),
                   &row[0]); // row is a vector<float>
```

And elsewhere in the code I attempt to delete the VBO like so:

```
glDeleteBuffersARB(1, &_vertexBufferID)
```

And it's on that line that I receive a segmentation fault. I have ensured that the correct OpenGL context is active at the time of deletion.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to delete a VBO just to change its size, calling `glBufferData` with a different size is enough. But maybe your actual application is more complex.

Comment: Can you run a memory checked, like valgrind?

Comment: @ChristianRau this actually works perfectly, but I'm still curious about this delete business.

Comment: @CoreyD For this we definitely need more code, since the presented code is just fine.

Comment: Does it happen on all attempts to delete VBOs? Or in just one instance? Have you verified that glDeleteBuffersARB is not a null function pointer? Also, why are you using the ARB suffix functions instead of the long-since-accepted-into-the-standard VBO functions?

Comment: The only reason for using ARB was because that's just what I found when we were researching how to speed up this 3D feature in the software. I will spend a little more time tomorrow looking at this to see what I can find.

Answer (score 0):

I debugged a similar issue with textures once and it was caused by a buffer overflow when filling it with data. Add a bounds check just before your glBufferSubDataARB calls to make sure you don't overflow with offset+size. Have a look at glGetBufferParameteriv with GL_BUFFER_SIZE as the parameter to get the bounds against which to check